# How to add an image at the end of a video from the terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, avconv

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. How can I add an image at the end of a video from the terminal? For example, I have a video called input.mp4, and I want to add an image called input.png showing my Facebook and Twitter accounts to the end of that video and output the results to a new video called output.mp4. How can I do that from the command-line?

```
 ________                          ________            ________
|        |                        |        |          |        |
| input  |  add image at the end  | input  |  avconv  | output |  
| mp4    |  ------------------->  | png    |  ----->  | mp4    | 
|________|                        |________|          |________|
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this with ffmpeg is create a video with just the png file

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.png -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p picture.mp4
```

Note: `-t 30`is how long you want the image to be displayed for in seconds

Then combine the two into a single video

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:input.mp4|picture.mp4" -c copy output.mp4
```

Hope that helps!

Good luck :)

Comment: I just try this in Ubuntu 18 and the concat dont works..

Comment: @mlacunza - This was for Ubuntu 14.04.  Please start a new question if you're having issues with a later version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Many commands work in all Linux and in most of the new versions, is valid my comment because it's an update of your post

Comment: @mlacunza - A valid point, but not relevant to the original post.  Either edit the original question to include all versions of Ubuntu, then edit the answer to reflect the change, *OR* start a new question if you need help.

Comment: Not relevant for you maybe, this answer is linked in many others threads, I'm just updated it and for that reason I use a COMMENT for it and not and  ANSWER, bye

Comment: Great solution. Much more successful than trying to encode it all at once. Note I used `yuvj420p` instead of `yuv420p` to match my video, and used an image editor to resize the images to match the video resolution first. For the latest on doing the concatenation, use the easy instructions here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate